# Instruments VM tracker is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, instruments

Same symptom as this issue [Why VM Tracker is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692242/why-vm-tracker-is-empty).

Using my iPhone5 running iOS 6, XCode 4.5, I start profiling my project (I've also tried running Instruments independently). I have made sure to enable automatic snapshotting (I've also tried manual snapshots). I can see the status in the VM tracker switch ever so briefly from "Idle" to "Analyzing Process", so it does seem to be doing something, however my VM tracker graph is always empty, as if there was no data.

There are some warnings in the Mac's Console as well as the iPhone's Console, but no errors and nothing specific to the VM tracker.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last time this happened to me, ensuring that the app was signed with a development certificate (as opposed to a distribution certification) fixed the problem for me.